# Have problems with run Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

Thats is my result so, error run code..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pya.marlon.com.pruebas.ExampleRXJava
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Working with some example RXJava maybe have problems with gradle code..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pya.marlon.com.pruebas"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions{
            enabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen', '../greendao/classes']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':greendao')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
}
```

whats problem with my Android Studio so version is 2.3.2 
i working with two modules in my project

Comment: I see that some your code throws exception about some your class, why do you blame android studio?

Comment: well i starting with rxjava so yesterday.. have problems in run with android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the exception message properly, it is clearly showing that `pya.marlon.com.pruebas.ExampleRXJava` class not found, possibly you did not include the above class.

One very good tutorial on RxJava can be found here [RxJava 2.0 - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)

Comment: ty for u answer. nice tutorial

Comment: If this answer helpful, please consider accepting... thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use RxJava in Android add the following dependency to your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.8
```

and have a look at this Tutorial [RXJava Android Article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)

Comment: well not add some one in classpath ? maybe